# Subtract DataLayer values to return in UETQ variable revenue script

Tags: google-tag-manager, bing, google-datalayer, conversion-tracking

The module installed in my Magento store "WeltPixel" does not account for discount value when calculating revenue, but it does produce a discount variable, so I'd like to subtract discount value from the e-commerce-total before returning to bing UETQ tag for variable revenue tracking.

I have a custom script that does the math and saves the value as a variable (constant) in GTM, which works with Analytics, but when I add that variable to the UETQ GTM tag, the results in my browser test returned that variable as  `gv:google_tag_manager["GTM-KHPSMZ"].macro(\'gtm111\'),gc:"USD"});` instead of the actually expected value e.g. 29.99.

How would I do this mathematical operation in tag manager in order to derive the revenue value I need and pass it on to Bing?

[image: Ecommerce Main Revenue Variable]

[image: Final Revenue calculation subtracting coupon value.]

[image: UETQ Tag Config]

[image: Tag Manager on-page results]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your variable setup? and how are you adding it to the tag?

Comment: Should still work. This is how GTM references variables internally.

Comment: Thank you! I have added screenshots of the two variables, the tag configuration and the resulting tag on the order success page.

Comment: Note in the bottom screenshot how ev: calculates correctly but gv: pulls code.